# Is there in pandas operation complementary (opposite) to groupby: groupby all columns except the specified one?

Tags: python, group-by, dataframe, pandas

I have a table (data frame) with many columns. Now I would like to average values in one of the columns. It means that I need to group by over all columns except the one over which I need to average. Of course I can write:

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])['vals'].mean()
```

But it would be nice if I could do something like:

```
df.groupby(['col6'], something='reverse')['vals'].mean()
```

Is it possible in pandas?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want? To compute the mean of one columns it is not needed to do a groupby operation: df['col6'].mean()

Comment: Mean, was just an example. In general, I would like to have a possibility to group by all columns except the mentioned ones.

Comment: It's better provide part of your data as the input, and your expected output.

Answer (score 3):

You are searching for the complementary columns to a list you have on hands. You can play with `df.columns`. It represents an `Index` object that allows some interesting manipulations.

`df.columns.drop(['col6'])` returns an `Index` with the list of columns passed as argument removed. You can convert it into a list and use it as the `groupby` argument:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.drop(['col6']).tolist())['vals'].mean()
```